# is there way to find the points with minimum distance between them using SQL from a 2D space?

Tags: sql, shortest-path

[image]

I Have this dataset. I need to find out the 2 points which is having minimim distance between them compared to distance between all other points in the 2D space. Can someone help me on how to do this using SQL?

Comment: (1) You need to define distance.  (2) Tag with the database you are using.

Comment: That's not nearest neighbor, that's "Closest pair of points". Nearest neighbor is when you ask about the nearest neighbor of a specific point, and while closest pair can be found by computing the nearest neighbor for all points, that's not the most computationally optimal way.

Comment: That being said, the answer by Gordon, while having O(n^2) complexity and better algorithms having O(n*logN) complexity, if you are not actually having performance problems you should probably stick to the shown O(n^2) algorithm, the other one is a recursive divide and conquer algo, probably not nice to program in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define distance.  One definition is Manhattan distance, which is the sum of the absolute values.  Using this definition:

```
select t1.*, t2.*
from t t1 join
     t t2
     on t1.id < t2.id
order by abs(t1.x - t2.x) + abs(t1.y - t2.y)
fetch first 1 row only;
```

Note:  This sort of operation is expensive and it is tricky to optimize.